# How to find list of files which are not accessed for last two month?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am creating a app which is used to download files from internet and saves into document directory.At one time that document directory occupied huge memory because user has saved more files.Now I decide to delete the files which are not accessed by user for last two months.I want to know Is there any in build Ios options to find list of files under document directory based on files modification date?please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think the array gives the information of file with modification date.

Try to create one function depending on date comparison and delete the files.

```
NSArray * arrayOfURLs = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:URL 
                                   includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLIsDirectoryKey, 
                                                                NSURLNameKey, 
                                                                NSURLFileSizeKey, 
                                                                NSURLContentModificationDateKey,
                                                                NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey]
                                                      options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles 
                                                        error:nil];
```

Comment: is it possible to get last access date of file??

this is based on modification date.

Answer (score 1):

To get  **Last File access date**

```
#include <sys/stat.h>


-(NSDate *)getFileAccessLastDateOfFile:(NSString *)aFilePath{
    struct stat output;
    int ret = stat([aFilePath fileSystemRepresentation], &output);
    struct timespec accessTime = output.st_atimespec;
    NSDate *aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:accessTime.tv_sec];
    return aDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `NSURL Class` documentation, it reads :

> `NSURLContentModificationDateKey` The time at which the resource was
>   most recently modified, returned as an `NSDate` object if the volume
>   supports modification dates, or nil if modification dates are
>   unsupported.

Then with NSDate's `timeIntervalSinceNow` you'll be able to find whether your files are more or less than 2 months old.